# .net core mvc inject EF dbcontext to AddIdentity method in Startup using Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I have created a .net core project.
I started with my own DB and migrated it using EF into the DataAccess project.
Now, I want to integrate .net core identity with my existing tables. I struggle to find some useful resources on how to do that.
The structure of the projects in my solution is as follows:

FrontProject
    |
    |-Controllers
    |- views 
    |-viewmodels 
    | - etc
    | - autofac containers injected into the fronted project in the startup file
BusinessLogic
    |
    |- services 
    |- DTOs
    | - autofac module
DataAccess
    |
    |- Models
    |- Autofac module for
    
    I added the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity to all 3 projects. I need to:
    1. Generate the tables for the Identity tables from the DataAccess project level.
    2. Somehow register the Identity Provider, which "normally" is done using:
    `services.AddIdentity<MyUser,IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContext>();`
    But I do not want to reference the DataAccess (which holds the DbContext) from the FrontProject.
    Can you please help on how to do this using the Autofac which I am already using for injecting dependencies between the projects?